# How to build a vanilla JS static website with multiple HTML files in Vite

Tags: vite, rollup

I have a my static website with vanilla JS in the following structure:

```
my_page/
├─ admin/
│  ├─ dashboard.html
├─ js/
│  ├─ dashboard.js
├─ about.html
├─ index.html
├─ vite.config.js
```

How would I need to configure Vite so it produces a /dist folder which still respects the given folder structure so I can just put this dist folder on my static webserver?

All examples I can find for this is that where there are multiple "index.html" in subdirectories.